# Push to Firebase via REST API with Priority

Tags: firebase

Is it possible to use the REST API to push an event to a list (via an HTTP POST) and also specify the priority of the item that is being pushed? Perhaps as a field in the JSON I am posting somehow?

Something like this (semi-pseudo-code):

```js
var myObj = {name: 'My Name', address: 'My Address'};
myObj['priority'] = 123;

$.post('http://demo.firebase.com/demo/testing.json', myObj);
```

I can do it the following way with the native Javascript library but this does not use the REST API:

```js
var fb = new Firebase('http://demo.firebase.com/demo/testing');
var foo = fb.push({name: 'My Name', address: 'My Address'});
foo.setPriority(1);
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes!  To post data with a priority, you can use:

```
var myObj = JSON.stringify({name: 'My Name', address: 'My Address', '.priority': 123});
$.post('http://demo.firebase.com/demo/testing.json', myObj);
```

If you want to post a raw value (e.g. "hello") with a priority, use:

```
var myObj = JSON.stringify({'.value': 'hello', '.priority': 123});
$.post('http://demo.firebase.com/demo/testing.json', myObj);
```

Comment: @Michael: It would be nice to have `.value` and `.priority` settings in the official docs.

Comment: @mattedgod Good point.  We do mention .priority, but not .value.  I've updated the docs and they should go live in a few days.  Thanks!

Comment: @Michael is this still the case? From your documentation (and my testing) it seems like you have to use PUT to set the priority ("Priority can be read with GET and written with PUT" from https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest-api.html). This makes it seem like you can only set the data on a node, not push additional data into it.

Comment: @jnevelson This is still the case.  If you just want to set the priority on some data in Firebase (without changing the rest of the data), you'd do a PUT to https:// YOUR.firebaseio.com/path/to/item/.priority/.json as the docs mention.  You use POST if you want the equivalent of push() [i.e. appending a new item to a Firebase location].  And then you can optionally include .priority if you want to set the priority on the new item (which is what this question was about).