# Push a raw value to Firebase via REST API

Tags: python, firebase

I am trying to use the `requests` library in Python to push data (a raw value) to a firebase location.

Say, I have `urladd` (the `url` of the location with authentication token). At the location, I want to push a `string`, say `International`. Based on the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10924774/push-to-firebase-via-rest-api-with-priority), I tried

```
data = {'.value': 'International'}

p = requests.post(urladd, data = sjson.dumps(data))
```

I get `<Response [400]>`. `p.text` gives me:

```
u'{\n  "error" : "Invalid data; couldn\'t parse JSON object, array, or value. Perhaps you\'re using invalid characters in your key names."\n}\n'
```

It appears that they key `.value` is invalid. But that is what the answer linked above suggests. Any idea why this may not be working, or how I can do this through Python? There are no problems with connection or authentication because the following works. However, that pushes an object instead of a raw value.

```
data = {'name': 'International'}

p = requests.post(urladd, data = sjson.dumps(data))
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: For a workaround, couldn't you just move up one level on the path?  For instance, if I'm trying to set myinstance.firebaseio.com/some/place to "International":  `requests.post('myinstance.firebaseio.com/some', {place: "International"});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer you've linked is a special case for when you want to assign a priority to a value. In general, '.value' is an invalid name and will throw an error.

If you want to write just "International", you should write the stringified-JSON version of that data. I don't have a python example in front of me, but the curl command would be:

curl -X POST -d "\"International\"" https://...

Comment: Thanks, Andrew. For anyone else who is looking how to do this in Python, I have posted an answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Andrew's answer above works. In case someone else wants to know how to do this using the `requests` library in Python, I thought this would be helpful.

```
import simplejson as sjson

data = sjson.dumps("International")

p = requests.post(urladd, data = data)
```

For some reason I had thought that the data had to be in a dictionary format before it is converted to stringified JSON version. That is not the case, and a simple string can be used as an input to `sjson.dumps()`.