# Editing Firebase priority via REST

Tags: rest, firebase

I want to edit the priority of a parent object when a child object is added.
I am using PHP and the REST APIs and adding the new child using POST.

But it appears that the .priority setting can only be made using PUT which resets the parent object.

I have read this post and answer:
[Push to Firebase via REST API with Priority](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10924774/push-to-firebase-via-rest-api-with-priority)
but it applies to setting priority for new objects.

Then I tried retrieving the contents of the parent object and resetting it using .value
but that is not working for me - possibly because the object being pushed is a complex one with child objects of it's own.

So is it possible, or will it be possible in the future to PUSH a new .priority setting?

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is that you set the priority directly by appending .priority to the end of your URL. ie:

```
curl https://SampleChat.firebaseIO-demo.com/users/tom/.priority/.json
```

If you want to set the priority at the same time that other data is written, you can do that as well. See Writing Priorities from the REST API in [the docs](https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest-api.html).

Note that priorities can only be written to locations that already contain data. If you try to write priority to a null location, the priority will be ignored and the REST call will return null.

There is no command that will both push an object and update the parent's priority at the same time (I'm having trouble coming up with a good use case for this -- leave a comment if you have something in mind).

Comment: I do have a case for pushing an object and updating the parent's priority, but I have no problem with this being a two-step process.
I have a messaging system and I want the recently commented on messages to list first, so when a comment (child object) is pushed, I want to update the parent's priority so it moves to the top.

But that is not something I think you should worry about if I can do it in 2 steps.

Answer (score 0):

*Responding to Andrew as another answer so that I can format the code:*

The command you suggest will get me the existing priority but I still do not see how to change the priority. I am using PHP and here is what I have tried:

```
$url = $urlToParent . '/.priority/.json';
$fields = '{ ".priority" : ' . $timeStamp . ' }';
$result = doSend($url, $fields, 'PUT');

$url = $urlToParent . '/.priority/.json';
$fields = '{ ' . $timeStamp . ' }';
$result = doSend($url, $fields, 'PUT');

$url = $urlToParent . '/.json';
$fields = '{ ".priority" : ' . $timeStamp . ' }';
$result = doSend($url, $fields, 'POST');
```

doSend() is a PHP function that uses POST or PUT to send data.

These different attempts either delete the entire object, delete the priority setting or return an error. I am sure there must be a way to do what I want, I just haven't hit on the right combination of URL, parameters and sending method.

Comment: It looks to me like you're trying to set the priority to an object. Priorities can only be numbers or strings. To stripping off those braces around the timestamp in the second option. 

I'll update the answer below with the equivalent PUT command.

Comment: Hmm... actually there might be a bug here. I'm investigating and will update when we have a diagnosis.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. Your great support is appreciated as always.

Comment: Happy to help! I haven't tracked it down yet, but I will soon.

Comment: Actually, it looks like the issue here may be that you were writing to a location that didn't yet exist. Priorities can only be written if data already exists on the server -- otherwise it is ignored! I'll update the answer below.

Comment: You were correct - I was trying to set the priority to an object.  
This is now working.  
  
    $url = $urlToParent . '/.priority/.json';
    $result = doSend($url, $timeStamp, 'PUT');